# Redirect Old wordpress url to new wordpress url

Tags: urls

What we did was delete a category to smooth out some confusion.  The old url was: http://uafnews.com/headlines/my-permalink  but now it is http://uafnews.com/my-permalink.  How could I have people who come to old url get to the article now with it's new url? I am so new to this part of web development.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use an .htaccess rule to manage that, but i don't know if WordPress handles that.

It would have to be something like

```
Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html http://example.com/newdirectory/newfile.html
```

More info at: [How do I redirect my site using a .htaccess file](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file?)

Comment: Actually you wold have problems with this in wordpress 'cause of the permalinks, 'cause i don't think you would like to hardwrite each link

Comment: I checked a post at the wordpress forums and they seem to have the same answer so give it a try http://wordpress.org/support/topic/redirect-rules

Comment: I appreciate all your help but after reading more on the links provided I was even more confused.

I have a large volume of stories which were taken out of the "headlines" category and I really am unaware of their urls.  I was hoping for some wild card which I could use to redirect from old url to the new url which is just minus the word headlines in the urls or would this be more like a rewrite rule.  I am just not sure.